# Ошибка в Python: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 16: invalid continuation byte"

Tags: python, json, кодировка, utf-8, byte

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Все Папки\Python\Jarvis\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    date = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\nikita\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 16: invalid continuation byte
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить ошибку!!!

Мне надо, чтобы код записывал `input()` в json файл.
Вот сам код.

```
import json

name = input("Введите название для Г.П.: ")

with open('config.json', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    date = json.load(f)
date['name'] = name
with open('config.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    json.dump(date, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Если не использую `encoding="utf-8"`, то записываются только знаки вопросов вместо букв.

Comment: Ну а с текущим текстом ошибки очевидно, что в файле config.json кодировка на самом деле не utf-8

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень помогло!!!